# Issue with Javascript Date Daylight Time Saving and oracledb-node

Tags: javascript, oracle, node-oracledb

I've some problems with extracting DateTime field from a database using `oracledb-node` driver.

I've in the database two records with DateTime field like this.

```
# |MY_DATE            |SESSIONTIMEZONE
1 |2020-05-02 00:00:00|Europe/Berlin 
2 |2020-03-02 00:00:00|Europe/Berlin
```

When I retrieve it with `oracledb-node` to convert it into JSON, the second record changes day.

**First Record**

```
Rest API (JSON)
"2020-05-01T22:00:00.000Z"
Javascript Date
Sat May 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell'Europa centrale)
```

**Second Record**

```
Rest API (JSON)
"2020-03-01T22:00:00.000Z"
Javascript Date
Sun Mar 01 2020 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell'Europa centrale)
```

I suppose that I'm getting in trouble with Daylight Saving Time.

Can someone help me with the right approach?

Thank you.

Comment: You've tagged this as a node-oracledb issue, however it appears to be a JS issue.  If I'm wrong, start by reviewing the [node-oracledb documentation on fetching dates](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#datehandling).

Comment: Thank you @ChristopherJones! You are right.
I've set the ORA_SDTZ='Europe/Berlin' environment variable before starting my node app according to the documentation link you provide and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```js
const dates = ["|2020-05-02 00:00:00|Europe/Berlin", "|2020-03-02 00:00:00|Europe/Berlin"];

const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
dates.forEach(str => {
  const [, dStr, tz] = str.split("|")
  const d = DateTime.fromISO(dStr.replace(" ", "T"), {
    zone: tz
  });
  console.log(d.toISO());
  console.log(d.toUTC().toISO());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.24.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [@Cristopher comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61692727/issue-with-javascript-date-daylight-time-saving-and-oracledb-node?noredirect=1#comment109145864_61692727) to my question, the problem was that my node.js backend code was working with a different Timezone compared to the one set in the oracle database.

Following the `node-oracledb` documentation about [How to fetch Datetime fields](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#datehandling), I've set the environment variable `ORA_SDTZ='Europe/Berlin'` according to the timezone of the database.

Some quick tips to help the troubleshooting:

**How to get the database Timezone**

```
SELECT sessiontimezone FROM DUAL;
```

**How to get the node.js environment TimeZone**

```js
console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)
```